# audio analog input + usb data cable = sound noises

Tags: usb, audio, noise

I connect my android smartphone from audio jack output to my pc audio input and get a good analog sound signal. But when I connect this smartphone to  the pc with usb data cable the analog sound becomes hissing e.g. music from smartphone overlaps with noises on pc.
Why does this happen?
How can I eliminate these noises? maybe I have to use some shielded cables? If yes - then audio or usb? or I need some sound direct box or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by adding ground loop noise filter like [this](https://www.xmpow.com/mpow-ground-loop-noise-isolator-for-car-audio-system-home-stereo-ma1.html)